# Anybody know how to remove the Default highlight colour from a WPF listbox that uses a DataTemplate as its listbox item?

Tags: wpf, listview, listbox, datatemplate

Anybody know how to remove the Default highlight colour from a listbox that uses a DataTemplate as its listbox item?

I can remove the style ok when I use a ControlTemplate as my listbox item style.

Comment: Set a Style to the ItemContainerStyle of the ListBox.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may use an `ItemContainerStyle` in addition to an `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="10"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Excellent stuff! I tried many variations of this and couldn't get it to work due to my DataTemplate style being based on the bound object type! Thanks again!